# Angular2 Error: SimpleChange ( core OnChanges interface ) alternative to Angular2.0.0-beta.7

Tags: angular

I was reading this part [OnChanges-interface](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/OnChanges-interface.html) the plunker below, works well is the page angular.io, but it is based on version 2.0.0-alpha.40

### <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AHrB6opLqHDBPkt4KpdT?p=preview)</kbd>

but trying to use Angular2.0.0-beta.7 and 8 no works.

Can something has changed?, if so what is the alternative for this case, in my IDE tells me error on the next line `SimpleChange`

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: {[propName: string]: SimpleChange}) <--
```

and this plunker does not work, the sample

### <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XKQl5st1OHjgkEZZ9FAn?p=preview)</kbd>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plunker which you say doesn't work has a few errors:

I've updated it, so it does work:

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/g6YWeuY3C7127DXhmZLA?p=preview)

Basically I've changed:

`<my-cmp [my-prop]="value"></my-cmp>` to `<my-cmp [myProp]="value"></my-cmp>`

And renamed the method `onChanges` to `ngOnChanges`

Naming of attribute bindings and native methods have changed since the alpha build. Camelcase is the standard now for attribute binding. And almost all angular methods start with `ng` now.

Comment: Note that dash cased properties still work, you'll just have to do `@Input('my-prop') myProp` since there's no more implicit conversion from dash case to camel case.

Comment: I have tested and in this case is not required implements OnChanges http://plnkr.co/edit/UUahf7z6K6c2r5PrKBOA?p=preview . Only import SimpleChange or OnChanges right?

Comment: Nor implement of `OnChanges` and the import of it is necessary. This function is always called on a change. The import of `SimpleChange` is necessary for the compiler